# How to rename a folder correct?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to edit folder names programmatically. On windows it works flawless - on linux it is kinda *broken* `A?A¶A¼` (Äöü).
Locales on unix works fine - using `en_US.UTF-8`
When I create a directory (called `Äöü`) on the same path as my script uses it shows correctly as `Äöü`. When Python generates the directory its visible as `A?A¶A¼`.

#### Input

`Äöü`

#### Actual Output

`A?A¶A¼`

#### Expected Output

`Aeoeue`

I have a set of characters that have to be replaced.

```
ä : ae        
Ä : Ae
ö : oe
Ö : Oe
ü : ue
Ü : Ue
á : a
à : a
Á : A
....
```

This is how I read the file:

```
def __getChars(file):
    chars = {}
    with open(file) as f:
        content = f.readlines()
    for c in content:
        c = c.split(':')
        x = c[0].strip()

        try:
            y = c[1].strip()
        except:
            y = ''
        chars[x] = y
    return chars
```

This is how I replace the names

```
def __replace(string):
    try:
        string = string.encode('utf8')
    except:
        pass
    for char in chars.keys():
        key = char
        value = chars[key]
        string = string.replace(key, value)
    return string
```

This is how I call `__replace()`

```
chars = __getChars(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'system', 'replace'))

for path in os.listdir(root):
    src = os.path.join(root, path)
    if os.path.isdir(src):
        dst = os.path.join(root, __replace(repr(path).decode('unicode-escape')))
        if src != dst:
            os.rename(src, dst)
```

Comment: You need to give the errors/unexpected output too. Basically, what works & what doesn't.

Comment: orig name: 'Äöü' output: 'A?A¶A¼'

Comment: Oh, that wasn't clear for me the way you wrote it. You should put it up explicitly as *expected output* & *actual output*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in this hack:

```
repr(path).decode('unicode-escape')
```

You can not be sure about bytecode encoding on different systems, even on Windows with different system encodings or differently compiled Python, e.g. CygWin or PyWin. The only sure method is to get the list of filenames in unicode by calling `listdir` with unicode path, e.g. `os.listdir(u'.')` or `os.listdir(root.decode('utf-8')):`. It is much better to do all filesystem operations in unicode.

I even wrote a similar simple program that works in both Python 2 and Python 3 without any hack and it can rename all files and directories in a tree to ASCII. Most of your substitutions, that only removes accents from letters can be done by

```
from unicodedata import normalize
out_str = normalize('NFKD', in_str).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
```